# End the process of the foxpro

Tags: foxpro

How can stop the current processing foxpro program? I forgot to add skip in my do while so my code looping infinitely. If I force to close the program(by ending the process) my DBF file will corrupted.

Comment: HI Victor Baccal - this is outside the scope of Stack Overflow, which is only about programming problems. I think you might find the right audience at [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), the site for Database Administration questions and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably too late for you now, but pressing Escape will break a running program, unless you've executed SET ESCAPE OFF.  You'll get Cancel/Suspend/Ignore options.

Answer (score 1):

Your DBF shouldn't be corrupted by forcing VFP to close.

Comment: When I force shutdown the table that being use during the process will corrupted.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it still happens to DBFs (it certainly did in the old days), but we still see our CDX and FPT get corrupted when VFP processes are killed or network connectivity is lost.  Corrupt FPTs tend to bloat to 2GB size very quickly.